# Move adjacent tab to split?

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way to move an adjacent tab in Vim to current window as a split?

While looking around I reached a mailing list discussion where someone said it's the reverse of the operation <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd> without providing the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am providing two solutions, the first one I checked myself and I can guarantee it's working. The second, I am trying soon.
First solution: install this plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1961 by simply creating the folder `~/.vim/plugin` and downloading the file `Tabmerge.vim` into the folder. Then, when you have two tabs and you type

```
:Tabmerge
```

you will merge the two tabs into one, splitted horizontally and `top` aligned. Check out the link to find a complete usage guide.

Alternatively, check out this page http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_current_window_between_tabs for the code of two functions to move current window between tabs. Here the functions (which I didn't try yet):

```
function MoveToPrevTab()
  "there is only one window
  if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1
    return
  endif
  "preparing new window
  let l:tab_nr = tabpagenr('$')
  let l:cur_buf = bufnr('%')
  if tabpagenr() != 1
    close!
    if l:tab_nr == tabpagenr('$')
      tabprev
    endif
    sp
  else
    close!
    exe "0tabnew"
  endif
  "opening current buffer in new window
  exe "b".l:cur_buf
endfunc
```

and

```
function MoveToNextTab()
  "there is only one window
  if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1
    return
  endif
  "preparing new window
  let l:tab_nr = tabpagenr('$')
  let l:cur_buf = bufnr('%')
  if tabpagenr() < tab_nr
    close!
    if l:tab_nr == tabpagenr('$')
      tabnext
    endif
    sp
  else
    close!
    tabnew
  endif
  "opening current buffer in new window
  exe "b".l:cur_buf
endfunc
```

Comment: Thanks, tabmerge was enough for my needs.

Comment: The second alternative was better for me.  
I've mapped them to `mt` and `mT` in normal mode because it's consistent with the `gt` and `gT` I use to navigate tabs.  Also, I used the vertical split alternative shown in that page (`vert topleft split` instead` of `sp`).

Answer (score 52):

The problem with your problem is that a tab is not tied to a specific buffer. You can have 10 windows with as many buffers in a tab so "moving a tab into a split" doesn't make much sense.

What makes more sense is "show buffer x into a split" which can be done with

```
:sb <name_of_buffer>
```

Comment: I'll upvote it but it makes sense for my case, because the buffers are opened in different tabs by the plugins I use. The plugins don't provide the option to open them in splits.

Comment: Well for one `MRU`, it allows me to open in current window or new tab (no splitting key).

Comment: Now how do you do this with a vertical split?

Comment: This is perfect! Starting with `:sb `, you can tab through all the opened buffers without having to type in their path and filename!

Comment: @malan over a year late but for future readers, a vertical split can be made using `:vert sb <buffer_name>`