# Gvim: Move tab to new window

Tags: vim, tabs, window

The opposite question seems to be asked a lot:  how to move a window into a new tab in an existing window.  What I'm hoping is that a tab that I have open in gvim can be moved out into its own window or into *another* existing window.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: "Window" as in "GUI window" or as in "split window" ?  And "tab" as in "everything that is displayed in that tab" or "the buffer that I opened in a tab because I'm used to do that in other editors"?

Comment: Heh.  Thought those distinctions might arise.  Window: GUI Window, Tab: GUI tab with a single buffer.

Comment: GUI windows are separate instances, moving one buffer from one instance to another would mean: finding the other instance, sending it an adhoc command, wiping out the buffer in the current instance. I think that you would loose a lot in the process if you don't take care. You should explain your usecase exactly.

Comment: Use case:  I opened too many "gui tabs" in one window instance.  I want to separate three of them into another window instance (they have related functionality, and I want to work with them separately).  Make sense?

Comment: See also [Move adjacent tab to split?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14688536) and [Switching from tab to splitted window in vi/vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18978068).

Answer (score 8):

### Same Vim instance

If that tab shows just a single window, you just have to note its *buffer number* (e.g. via `:ls` or `:echo bufnr('')`, or by including it in the *statusline*), and then close the tab via `:close` (`:set hidden` helps with modified buffers), then going to the target tab / window, and re-opening the buffer there via `:buf N` or `:sbuf N`.

If you need to support multiple windows in a tab page, you'd have to write a custom command / mapping that first remembers the buffers, and then applies the above steps for all of them.

### Different Vim instances

**Edit**: The above is for movement *within a single Vim instance*. If you want to move a buffer to **another GVIM instance**, you first have to `:bdelete` it in the current Vim, to avoid *swap file* messages. Launching in new instances is easy:

```
:execute 'bdelete | !start gvim' shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)
```

This passes the (full absolute) path of the current file to a fresh GVIM.

To move a file to an existing GVIM (you need to know its `v:servername`), you need to use the remote client-server communication (`:help remote.txt`), e.g. by sending a similar `:drop` command via `remote_send()`, like this:

```
:execute 'bdelete | call remote_send("GVIM1", ":drop " . ' . string(fnameescape(expand('%:p'))) . '. "\<CR>")'
```

Comment: Informational as ever, Ingo!  Hey - is there a command to open a buffer in a new window with :Winopen or some such thing?  (I'd be interested in creating a mapping to handle all of this.)

Comment: Thanks :-) `:buf N` opens buffer `N` in the current window, `:sbuf N` in a new, split buffer`, `:vert sbuf N` vertically. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not quite.  I meant to a new GUI window.  Does that clarify it?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You want a completely new GVIM. That's hard.

Comment: I've added something to my answer. I hope that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can "move" the current buffer to a second GVim instance:

```
:!gvim --remote %
:bw
```

Note that Vim *must* be built with the `+clientserver` option.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

You cannot move a vim tab into a window, no matter new or existing. Because a vim tab page is a collection of windows. You cannot move a collection of windows into one single window.